# FRR not sending BGP advertisements on debian 11

Tags: debian, routing, bgp

I am trying to get bgp  working in a lab environment between 4 routers. I have 1 central router and 3 branches. 3 of the 4 machines are debian11 machines and 1 branch is a windows server 2019 which I also set up bgp.

"show bgp summary" shows that all neighbours are connected:

```
ISP# sh bgp summary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
IPv4 Unicast Summary:                                                                                                                                
BGP router identifier 120.116.7.254, local AS number 62000 vrf-id 0                                                                                  
BGP table version 8                                                                                                                                  
RIB entries 9, using 1728 bytes of memory                                                                                                            
Peers 3, using 64 KiB of memory                                                                                                                      
Peer groups 3, using 192 bytes of memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Neighbor        V         AS   MsgRcvd   MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ  Up/Down State/PfxRcd   PfxSnt                                                   
120.115.7.65    4      64000        95        84        0    0    0 01:19:51            1        0                                                   
120.116.9.129   4      63000     30123     30125        0    0    0 1d01h05m            0        0                                                   
120.116.7.1     4      61000      1525      1528        0    0    0 00:29:49            0        0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Total number of neighbors 3
```

The central router named ISP config:

```
Current configuration:                                                                                                                               
!                                                                                                                                                    
frr version 7.5.1                                                                                                                                    
frr defaults traditional                                                                                                                             
hostname ISP                                                                                                                                         
log syslog informational                                                                                                                             
no ipv6 forwarding                                                                                                                                   
service integrated-vtysh-config                                                                                                                      
!
router bgp 62000
neighbor Branch1 peer-group                                                                                                                               
neighbor Branch1 remote-as 64000                                                                                                                          
neighbor Branch2 peer-group                                                                                                                              
neighbor Branch2 remote-as 63000                                                                                                                         
neighbor Branch3 peer-group                                                                                                                               
neighbor Branch3 remote-as 61000                                                                                                                          
neighbor 120.115.7.65 peer-group Branch1                                                                                                                  
neighbor 120.116.9.129 peer-group Branch2                                                                                                               
neighbor 120.116.7.1 peer-group Branch3                                                                                                                   
!                                                                                                                                                    
address-family ipv4 unicast                                                                                                                           
network 120.116.7.0/26                                                                                                                               
network 120.115.7.64/26                                                                                                                              
network 120.116.9.128/25                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
redistribute kernel                                                                                                                                  
redistribute connected                                                                                                                               
neighbor Branch1 route-map Branch1 in                                                                                                                          
neighbor Branch1 route-map Branch1 out                                                                                                                         
neighbor Branch2 route-map Branch2 in                                                                                                                       
neighbor Branch2 route-map Branch2 out                                                                                                                      
neighbor Branch3 route-map Branch3 in                                                                                                                          
neighbor Branch3 route-map Branch3 out                                                                                                                        
exit-address-family                                                                                                                                 
!                                                                                                                                                    
route-map Branch3 permit 10                                                                                                                                
match interface ens161                                                                                                                               
match peer 120.116.7.1                                                                                                                              
!                                                                                                                                                    
route-map Branch1 permit 20                                                                                                                                
match peer 120.115.7.65                                                                                                                             
!                                                                                                                                                    
route-map Branch2 permit 30                                                                                                                              
match peer 120.116.9.129                                                                                                                            
!                                                                                                                                                    
line vty                                                                                                                                             
!                                                                                                                                                    
end
```

One of the branch router's conf:

```
Current configuration:                                                                                                          
!                                                                                                                               
frr version 7.5.1                                                                                                               
frr defaults traditional                                                                                                        
hostname Branch3                                                                                                               
log syslog informational                                                                                                        
no ipv6 forwarding                                                                                                              
service integrated-vtysh-config                                                                                                 
!                                                                                                                               
router bgp 61000                                                                                                                 
neighbor ISP peer-group                                                                                                         
neighbor ISP remote-as 62000                                                                                                    
neighbor 120.116.7.62 peer-group ISP                                                                                            
!                                                                                                                               
address-family ipv4 unicast                                                                                                      
network 120.116.5.0/26                                                                                                          
network 120.116.8.0/24                                                                                                          
neighbor ISP route-map ISP in                                                                                                   
neighbor ISP route-map ISP out                                                                                                 
exit-address-family                                                                                                            
!                                                                                                                               
route-map ISP permit 1                                                                                                           
match peer 120.116.7.62                                                                                                        
!                                                                                                                               
line vty                                                                                                                        
!                                                                                                                               
end
```

I don't know what I'm missing since the BGP Windows Server sent his pseudo network(120.116.6.0/24) which I gave him shown here:

```
K>* 0.0.0.0/0 [0/0] via 10.0.255.254, ens192, 1d01h51m                                                                                               
C>* 10.0.0.0/16 is directly connected, ens192, 1d01h51m                                                                                              
C>* 120.116.7.0/26 is directly connected, ens161, 1d01h51m                                                                                           
C>* 120.115.7.64/26 is directly connected, ens256, 1d01h51m                                                                                          
C>* 120.116.9.128/25 is directly connected, ens224, 1d01h51m                                                                                         
B>* 120.116.6.0/24 [20/0] via 120.116.7.65, ens256, weight 1, 00:58:05                                                                               
ISP#
```

(Side note: ens192 is the interface connected to the public internet to install packages)

And like the other networks (that are confiugured) this route won't be advertised forward by ISP.
As seen in the Branch config I thought that maybe I could send network advertisements to ISP but no hope.

net.ip4.ip_forward is set to 1

firewalls are all disabled

Why won't FRR send BGP advertisements but receive them fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
router bgp <AS>
no bgp network import-check
```

https://github.com/FRRouting/frr/issues/12266